# Using NetworkInterface get current connection name and ip for vpn

Tags: windows, vb.net

I'm adapting a vpn vb6 app for vb.net. How do I, using NetworkInterface, get the current active connection name and ip address? I'm aware that if the vpn is active the ethernet or wifi connection shouldn't be active, right? My app should list the current active connection name and ip address, regardless of using a Windows vpn connection (should show vpn name and ip), or OpenVPN (should show most likely name as Ethernet 2), or a vpn app (most likely name as Ethernet 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, windows shows you all the interfaces and active must be at least one of them adding to the vpn. Cause the vpn (virtuell private network) tunnels though your network connection.

```
   Dim interfaces As NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface() = NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
  If interfaces.GetLongLength(0) > 0 Then
    For Each Interface As NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface In interfaces
      If String.Compare(Interface.Description, "Tap") > 0 And String.Compare(Interface.Description, "Teredo") < 0 Then
      End if
    Next
  End if
```

this abouve lokks for an active openvpn connection. You can debug it and lokks if other interfaces methods are better suiting to identify your vpn connection

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code I've got so far:

```
 Public Function GetConnectionList() As List(Of String())
        Dim conList As New List(Of String())
        Dim conName As String = "dummy"
        Dim last_conName As String = "dummy"
        Dim conIPstr As String = "dummy"
        Dim str As String

        conList.Clear()
        Dim nic As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

        If nic.GetLongLength(0) > 0 Then

            For Each netadapter As NetworkInterface In nic

                conName = netadapter.Name
                Dim strArr As String() = New String(2) {"dummy", "dummy", "dummy"}

                If Not conName.Contains("VirtualBox") _
                    And Not conName.Contains("Loopback") _
                    And conName <> "Ethernet" _
                    And conName <> "Wi-Fi" Then

                    strArr(0) = conName
                    If netadapter.OperationalStatus = OperationalStatus.Up Then
                        strArr(1) = "Current Sataus: Active"
                        Try
                            conIPstr = GetMyIPstr()
                        Catch e As Exception
                            MessageBox.Show("Error: Function GetConnectionList: Error returning IP Address" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & e.Message)
                        End Try
                        strArr(2) = conIPstr
                    Else
                        strArr(1) = "Current Sataus: Not Active"
                        strArr(2) = "No IP Address"
                    End If

                    conList.Add(strArr)

                End If
            Next
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Function GetConnectionList: No Net Adapter List")
        End If

        Return conList

    End Function

     Private Function GetMyIPstr() As String
        Dim client As New WebClient
        Dim s As String = "No IP Address"
        '// Add a user agent header in case the requested URI contains a query.
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR1.0.3705;)")
        Dim baseurl As String = "http://checkip.dyndns.org/"
        ' with proxy server only:
        Dim proxy As IWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()
        proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        client.Proxy = proxy
        Dim data As Stream
        Try
            data = client.OpenRead(baseurl)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("open url " & ex.Message)
            Exit Function
        End Try
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(data)
        s = reader.ReadToEnd()
        data.Close()
        reader.Close()
        s = s.Replace("<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>", "").Replace("</body></html>", "").ToString()
        'MessageBox.Show(s)
        'Me.Text = s
        Return s
    End Function
```